# Doubt in proof of Dual of the direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

If $M$ and $N$ are subspaces of $V$, and if $V = M \oplus N$, then

$$V' = M^\perp \oplus N^\perp$$

where $W^\perp$ is the annihilator of $W$.

I didn't understand how to prove both of the annihilators to be disjoint.

EDIT:- according to me, in order to prove M⊥ and N⊥ disjoint, we must prove that 0 is the only linear function taking both of them to 0, but somehow i am not able to get a feel of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the two annihilator spaces are not disjoint since $0$ is in both of them, but their intersection is *trivial*: suppose that $\phi$ is in the annihilator of both $M$ and $N$. Then $\phi(v) = 0$ for all $v \in M$ and all $v \in N$, that is, for all $v \in M \oplus N = V$ by linearity, so $\phi = 0$.

Comment: can you please explain about that linearity part

Comment: @Manish: Let $v \in V$ be any vector. Then since $V = M \oplus N$, you can find $m \in M$ and $n \in N$ so that $v = m + n$. Now you know that $\phi(m) = \phi(n) = 0$ and it follows that $\phi(v) = \phi(m+n) = \phi(m) + \phi(n) = 0 +0 = 0$.

Comment: thats ok, but i was asking if ϕ=0, for all v∈V, then what do you conclude..sorry to not understand easily

Comment: You have to show that something lying in both $M^\perp$ and $N^\perp$ has to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi \in V^*$ vanishes on $M$ and on $N$, then it clearly vanishes on $M \oplus N = V$, hence $\phi = 0$.